# Javascript string interpolation like in ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-interpolation

I am having the following code in my JS.

```
$('#ytResultsList').append('<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="' + item.id.videoId + '></a></li>');
```

As you can see from the above code, in HTML the result is like below.

```
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" bruvbiwlwfi=""></a></li>
```

I want the URL to be like below in HTML.

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bruvbiwlwfi"
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are formatting your `href` incorrectly. You need to move your closing `"` to after the variable like this:

```
$('#ytResultsList').append('<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + item.id.videoId + '"></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

quotation marks are your problem
try:

```
$('#ytResultsList').append('<li><a href=\'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + item.id.videoId + '\'></a></li>');
```

Comment: It too works. But I don't get it easily like the quotation answer above.

Answer (score 1):

[Templatestrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) do have [pretty good support](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20strings) in modern browsers and can be polyfilled if you need to support older ones - note the backticks:

```
const videoId = 'bruvbiwlwfi'
const url = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`
=> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bruvbiwlwfi"
```